# Cчётчик гостей

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, как узнать количество гостей которые просматривают сайт, именно гостей, а не зарегистрированных пользователей?

Answer (score 1):

Обычно делают сессии в базе и по этим сессиям и смотрят.

аля:

`sessionId | userId | ....`

```
select count(*) as cnt from sessions where userId=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fp = fopen("log.txt","r");
$x = fread($fp,filesize($fp));
fclose($fp);
if (isset($_COOKIE['1']) == false)
{
  $fp = fopen("log.txt","w");
  $x++;
  fwrite($fp,$x);
  fclose($fp);
}
setcookie(1,1,time()+31536000);
echo $x." посетителей";
```

Самый простой.Читает из файла, сколько уже зашло, если в куках ничего нет, то увеличивает число, посылает куки всегда и надолго, если куки не включены у пользователя будет плохо, но вконтактиках щас сидят все, так что мало вероятно, ещё можно по ip, но тогда уже лучше в базах хранить, а лучше поставить какой-нить счётчик LiveInternet))